# Check if glDrawElements doesn't produce any fragments

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is there any way to check if OpenGL draw command has produced any fragments? For example in the case of Depth Peeling for a transparent object I don't want to render consequent iterations if during the previous iteration no additional fragments were produced during the draw calls due to discards or depth test failures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if there was a way (and [there sort of is](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_pipeline_statistics_query.txt)), you shouldn't do this. To do what you're talking about would require having the CPU wait until the GPU has *finished* rendering the particular iteration before issuing the rendering command for the next one. This is pretty bad for performance, both CPU and GPU.